# System.Text.Json UTF-8 Deserialization confusion

Tags: c#, json, deserialization, .net-6.0, system.text.json

I have a generic JSON file caching service that will take a .NET object and write it as default/typical minified JSON to the disk. While this works nicely, I wanted to try improving this a bit, by storing and working with UTF-8 byte arrays.

```
// getFunc() is a Func<T> that just defines what the shape of the data is
byte[] bytes = JsonSerializer.SerializeToUtf8Bytes(getFunc());
using FileStream stream = File.Create(filePath);
await JsonSerializer.SerializeAsync(stream, bytes);
await stream.DisposeAsync();
```

In trying to get this to work, I'm working with a sample/dummy JSON object that I grabbed online and generated the corresponding .NET POCOs. When this code runs, the serialization works and my JSON file has this contents:

```
"eyJkYXRhIjpbeyJ0eXBlIjoiYXJ0aWNsZXMiLCJpZCI6IjEiLCJhdHRyaWJ1dGVzIjp7InRpdGxlIjoiSlNPTjpBUEkgcGFpbnRzIG15IGJpa2UiLCJib2R5IjoiVGhlIHNob3J0ZXN0IGFydGljbGUgZXZlciIsImNyZWF0ZWQiOiIyMDIzLTA4LTA5VDA3OjI1OjQwLjI5MTQ4MDQtMDQ6MDAiLCJ1cGRhdGVkIjoiMjAyMy0wOC0wOVQwNzoyNTo0MC4yOTE1MTY5LTA0OjAwIn0sInJlbGF0aW9uc2hpcHMiOnsiYXV0aG9yIjp7ImRhdGEiOnsiaWQiOiI0MiIsInR5cGUiOiJwZW9wbGUifX19fV0sImluY2x1ZGVkIjpbeyJ0eXBlIjoicGVvcGxlIiwiaWQiOiI0MiIsImF0dHJpYnV0ZXMiOnsibmFtZSI6Ik1hdHQiLCJhZ2UiOjMyLCJnZW5kZXIiOiJtYWxlIn19XX0="
```

When decoded through an online Base64 decoder, provides the following information:

```
{"data":[{"type":"articles","id":"1","attributes":{"title":"JSON:API paints my bike","body":"The shortest article ever","created":"2023-08-09T07:25:40.2914804-04:00","updated":"2023-08-09T07:25:40.2915169-04:00"},"relationships":{"author":{"data":{"id":"42","type":"people"}}}}],"included":[{"type":"people","id":"42","attributes":{"name":"Matt","age":32,"gender":"male"}}]}
```

So here's where the confusion is: in trying to deserialize this byte[] from UTF-8 (following this documentation section - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/how-to?pivots=dotnet-6-0#deserialize-from-utf-8) it says "this example assumes the JSON is in a byte array named jsonUtf8Bytes". This makes it seem like all that should be needed here would be these 2 lines, however these throw a pretty bland JSON exception that is causing me some grief

```
ReadOnlySpan<byte> jsonSpan = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
var content = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(jsonSpan);
```

```
System.Text.Json.JsonException: The JSON value could not be converted to MyProject.Rootobject. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 502.
   at System.Text.Json.ThrowHelper.ThrowJsonException_DeserializeUnableToConvertValue(Type propertyType)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters.ObjectDefaultConverter`1.OnTryRead(Utf8JsonReader& reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state, T& value)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.TryRead(Utf8JsonReader& reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state, T& value)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.ReadCore(Utf8JsonReader& reader, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.ReadFromSpan[TValue](ReadOnlySpan`1 utf8Json, JsonTypeInfo jsonTypeInfo, Nullable`1 actualByteCount)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize[TValue](ReadOnlySpan`1 utf8Json, JsonSerializerOptions options)
```

After hammering away trying to make this work, I was finally able to get the byte[] file to deserialize back to the original .NET object, but only after deserializing the file as a string and converting from base64 to byte[] was I then able to deserialize back to the original object:

```
var fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
var value = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<string>(fileBytes);
byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(value);
var content = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(bytes);
```

This feels a bit redundant to deserialize back to the original object. I feel as though there is something I'm missing but I don't know what I don't know. When the Deserialize call throws an exception, that byte array has a length of `502` but is only ~`374` after adding the additional code to convert from base64 to receive the byte[] that can be deserialized. Am I missing something or is this the expected way to go about working with objects stored as byte[]?

Comment: Why did you serialise the object twice in the first place? You serialised it twice, that's why you need to deserialise it twice too. You could write the `bytes` directly to a file, or do `JsonSerializer.SerializeAsync(stream, getFunc());`directly.

Comment: You're trying to serialize the same data *twice*. You're serializing the data to JSON *bytes*, then serializing the *bytes* as JSON. Bytes are serialized as BASE64 in JSON. Remove `await JsonSerializer.SerializeAsync(stream, bytes);`. You can use `File.WriteAllBytes(bytes)`. Or, instead of `SerializeToUtf8Bytes`, you can use `JsonSerializer.SerializeAsync(stream, getFunc())`

Comment: "I wanted to try improving this a bit, by storing and working with UTF-8 byte arrays." Why would doing that "improve" it?

Comment: The text is already UTF8 in either case. `SerializeToUtf8Bytes` results in *worse* performance because it keeps all the file data in memory, while `SerializeAsync` would write them to disk immediatelly

Comment: SMH thank you very much @Sweeper @PanagiotisKanavos that really tripped me up. I had `SerializeAsync(stream, getFunc())` originally but in trying to make the edits to use the `..Utf8Bytes` method didn't realize I was now double serializing. Reverting the serialization back let the deserialization with `ReadOnlySpan<byte>` work as expected. Curious though that the `SerializeToUtf8Bytes` isn't as useful as it seems -- I was just going off this little bit MS included in their docs: `Serializing to a UTF-8 byte array is about 5-10% faster than using the string-based methods.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bug is in the code - it's serializing the data twice *and* using at least twice as much RAM

1. The data is serialized to JSON, as UTF8 bytes and then
2. The bytes are again serialized to JSON. BASE64 is the representations of bytes in JSON

There's no reason to try and use `SerializeToUtf8Bytes`. The JsonSerializer class already uses `Utf8JsonWriter`, along with buffers coming from a buffer pool. It's already reusing buffers where needed.

The source code shows that [SerializeAsync](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Text.Json/src/System/Text/Json/Serialization/JsonSerializer.Write.Stream.cs#L72) passes the call to [JsonTypeInfo.SerializeAsync](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/e35c8214a94827ded526b0011b5c9e86faa82197/src/libraries/System.Text.Json/src/System/Text/Json/Serialization/Metadata/JsonTypeInfoOfT.WriteHelpers.cs#L62).

```
JsonTypeInfo<TValue> jsonTypeInfo = GetTypeInfo<TValue>(options);
jsonTypeInfo.Serialize(utf8Json, value);
```

That method in turn uses cached writers with buffers from a reusable pool:

```
using var bufferWriter = new PooledByteBufferWriter(Options.DefaultBufferSize);
Utf8JsonWriter writer = Utf8JsonWriterCache.RentWriter(Options, bufferWriter);

try
{
    SerializeHandler(writer, rootValue!);
    writer.Flush();
}
finally
{
    // Record the serialization size in both successful and failed operations,
    // since we want to immediately opt out of the fast path if it exceeds the threshold.
                    
    OnRootLevelAsyncSerializationCompleted(writer.BytesCommitted + writer.BytesPending);

    Utf8JsonWriterCache.ReturnWriter(writer);
}
```